# assemblies failed load (i put more information to explain my last question)

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to load assemblies outside the appbase(more information)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705051/how-to-load-assemblies-outside-the-appbasemore-information)

Kragen,

For more information, i have an application who running in a distributed domain and the goal of that application: it's to test a collection of assemblies tests. When the application starts,it loads assemblies from an array of assemblies path who aren't in the same location of the application and when i test this application on my local desktop :it's works well (loads and make reflection from assemblies etc..) but from the cluster computers, it can't load assemblies`FileNotFoundException.Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified`.

See [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6705051/834130)